# Создание и добавление в массив "на лету"

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь обновлять значение переменной, если это строка, то переводить ее в массив c одним индексом.

```
 if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
     params = [].push(params);
 }
```

Но данный код не работает, впрочем как и этот

```
params = [][0] = params;
```

Имеется ли возможность обновить переменную, создав новый массив и запушив в него значение, при этом не создавая других переменных?

Comment: Пока совсем не ясно, что вы хотите. Может пример input и output для наглядности?

Comment: Так, может, просто `params = [params];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать массив из одного элемента можно так:

```js
var params = "str";
if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
  params = [params];
}
console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

А такой вариант не подойдет?

```js
var arr = 'Зинаида Павловна';
arr = arr.slice() + ' умница!'
console.log(arr)
```